# Creating an RSA private key in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to rewrite some Java (Android) code in ObjC on the iPhone. The code will do a basic web service call and needs to set some headers with authentication information.

One part of that information is an encrypted hash of the data I am sending over.

The Java version calculates an SHA256 signature using an RSA private key that is generated on the phone. The private key is generated using a seed that I have available.

The (simplified) java code is as follows:

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSAEncryption");

// I get the private key bytes from an outside source
EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
sig.initSign(keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec));

sig.update(/* insert my data here */);
return sig.sign();
```

Now I'm trying to recreate this in iOS and ObjC. Doing the SHA256 signature calculation is easy, but I don't see how to create a private RSA key easily. I would prefer to use the built-in API's if there are any available, but if I must use a third party library like OpenSSL then I can live with that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people (citation needed) elect to go with the third party OpenSSL library, not only because rolling your own crypto is hard, but also because their is a good chance you'll create bad crypto if you're not already experienced with it.

That said, nothing prevents you from writing your own SHA256 hash, in straight C or C++ if you like, although I think you'll find your PRNG options lacking and find yourself spending altogether way too much time on entropy pools and the like.

If you do come across a good SHA256 primitive without all the extra baggage of OpenSSL, I'd love to learn about it too! But so far I haven't seen one.

Comment: Writing my own crypto library is out of the question. Not only would it be terribly hard and way too much work, but I would probably end up with a really poor implementation.

Comment: But OpenSSL will do what I need? Then I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: I always end up with the same conclusion, even as a Mathematician and crypto-nerd. Being able to rock the math in no way guarantees that my implementation won't be garbage. OpenSSL is bulky, but will get the job done. If you're looking to pick and choose elements, I've [enjoyed this project from Brad Conte](https://github.com/B-Con/crypto-algorithms). Lot's of core features rolled out in straight C. Please update if you find something else cool!